# How to stop a nested for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I want both loops to stop as soon as I find an object that has the same position in x.

Here is my C++ code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i){
    for(int j = i; j > 0; --j){
        if (s[i].positionX == s[j-1].positionX){
            s[i].positionY = s[j-1].positionY; 
        }
    }
}
```

If I use `break;` it only breaks out of the inner for loop.  What is the best way to stop both?

**Options:**

1. Set the indexes of the loops to max value (or min value) to terminate the loop.
2. Put all this inside a function and use return.
3. Use a goto
4. Use a Lambda
5. Set a boolean stop code to true, break, then listen for break and break out of other loop?
6. ?

Comment: would a while statement (e.g. while x != y) solve your problem?

Comment: break; can fix the problem

Comment: I already tried break in the if statement but it did not work.

Comment: Since nothing in the inner loop uses `j`, the only thing the inner loop does is skip the `if` statement when `i` is zero. Is your code correct? Perhaps you intended `j` where there is currently `i-1`?

Comment: yes sorry. its should be s[j-1].positionX and s[j-1].positionY

Comment: 6. Throw an exception :P

Comment: 7. Use `setjmp`/`longjmp` (no, don't actually do that).

Answer (score 4):

To break out of the innermost `for` loop, use `break`.

To break out of the outermost one, either use `goto` or use a combination of `break` and a "should stop" flag.

Comment: Don't use goto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: The `goto` debate is a semi-religious opinion-strewn minefield; I won't censor my answer just to favor One Right Way. The OP can decide for himself which variant he prefers: both are present.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest lambda:

```
auto do_work = [&] {
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i){
       for(int j = i; j > 0; --j){
           if (s[i].positionX == s[i-1].positionX){
               s[i].positionY = s[i-1].positionY; 
               return;
           }
       }
   }
};

do_work();  //you can call this multiple times if you need to!
```

No `break`, no `goto`. :-)

It serves the same purpose as `break` and `goto` in this case, but the technique seems to be clean, at least to me. Also, once you have the lambda with **a name** (a *good* name), you can use it multiple times if you need to — so this technique increases the code readability and encourages code-reuse.

Of course, if you don't need to call this multiple times, then probably you don't need a name. You just could do this:

```
[&]
{
   //your code with the added return statement.
}();
```

But as I said, `name` increases readability even if you don't call it multiple times.

---

If you cannot use lambda for some reason, then you could still avoid using an extra variable such as `stop` and the extra work involving it (as @ssantos's answer suggested):

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i){
    for(int j = i; j > 0; --j){
        if (s[i].positionX == s[i-1].positionX){
            s[i].positionY = s[i-1].positionY; 
            i = sizeArray; //it will break the outer loop!
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: While you're suggesting alternatives to `break`, what about throw/catch (*ducks*). (+1)

Comment: But a `return;` which exactly serves the same purpose as `break` and `goto`.

Comment: In fact, he doesn't even need to store it. (`([](){})()`) - That is, assuming he only wants to call it once.

Comment: @glglgl: It serves the same purpose, but seems to be clean, at least to me. Also, once you have the lambda with **a name** (a good one), you can use it multiple times if you need to. It is a technique which has other usages which is not possible with `break` and `goto` while keeping your code neat and clean.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you ask for stopping a `for` loop. The keyword you're looking for is [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/37zc9d2w.aspx). However, if you want to exit both `for` loops, you'll need to add a variable to your code.-

```
bool stop = false;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i){
    for(int j = i; j > 0; --j){
        if (s[i].positionX == s[i-1].positionX){
            s[i].positionY = s[i-1].positionY; 
            stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (stop) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the code you posted in its own function and `return` out of it after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop a `for` loop with `break`.

With nested `for` loops, things are not so easy. You can achieve your goal

- either with setting a flag (`done = 1;` and use it with `for(int j = i; j > 0 && !done; --j)`)
- or with `goto`. Although `goto` is frowned upon by some people, it can, if used correctly and with care, be a legitimate solution for some problems, such as error handling, or in general, "finished handling".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
bool match = false; 

for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray && !match; ++i){
    for(int j = i; j > 0 && !match; --j){
        if ( match = ( s[i].positionX == s[i-1].positionX ) ){
            s[i].positionY = s[i-1].positionY; 
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is the following

```
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeArray; ++i){
      int j = i;
      while ( j != 0 && s[i].positionX != s[i-1].positionX ) --j;
      if ( j != 0 ) {
           s[i].positionY = s[i-1].positionY; 
           break; 
      }
}
```